# Convert float (YYYY) to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm relatively new to SQL, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.  I've been trying for too long now to get this to work.

I have a column in table A that is a float column called ConstructionYear.  It is populated with a simple 4 digit year (i.e. 2010, 2005, 1972, etc.).  I need to populate table B's YearBuilt datetime field using these years.  I've searched and searched and tried all sorts of different combinations of convert() and cast() that I've found online, but it's not working.

What I would like to happen is this:

> '2008' -> '2008-01-01 00:00:00.000'
>
> '2005' -> '2005-01-01 00:00:00.000'
>
> '1986' -> '1986-01-01 00:00:00.000'

Instead of what is currently happening (using `CAST(ConstructionYear AS DATETIME)`):

> '2008' -> '1905-07-02 00:00:00.000'
>
> '2010' -> '1905-07-04 00:00:00.000'
>
> '1984' -> '1905-06-08 00:00:00.000'

EDIT: Solution: `cast(convert(varchar,@ConstructionYear) AS DATETIME)`

So my problem had 2 main causes (other than me being new to sql).

1. I didn't know about the 1900 epoch that SQL Server uses for datetime.  I could tell something was going on because of all teh 1905 datetimes i saw, but i didn't know that it was taking my 2005 year and counting it as days from 1900.
2. The year 1753.  Why is 1753 the earliest year we can use?  I probably had the right syntax at some point before i posted my question here, but it didn't run because my data had some years predating 1753.  I assumed the error was with my code.

Comment: Float seems a bad way to store an integer, year in this case. Depending on how the field is populated you could get slightly off values that would need to be truncated or rounded prior to the cast to (small)int or char(4)

Comment: Agreed, an int column would be far more appropriate, lest you get a 1984.535 in there somehow

Comment: Agreed.  I unfortunately am not in control of the structure of these tables, or how they are initially populated by our client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this example:

```
DECLARE @ConstructionYearas FLOAT
SET @ConstructionYear = 2012
SELECT FloatToDatetime = CAST(convert(varchar(4),@ConstructionYear) as datetime)
```

It will output:

`2012-01-01 00:00:00.000`

---

Basically use:

`CAST(convert(varchar(4),@ConstructionYear) as datetime)`

where `@ConstructionYear` is your `Float` variable

Hope it helps!

Comment: Very true @AaronBertrand I don't know how I missed that, thx!

Comment: I just don't like the use of varchar when it's possible to treat the float, a **number**, *as a number*. Use date math instead! I am a seasoned SQL Server developer/dba and I didn't even know that Convert(datetime, '2012') would work... that is NOT a valid date in my book. I don't trust it. And I trust my instincts. I can't vote for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Besides [@Ghost's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11461898/128165) answer, if you are using SQL SERVER 2012

You can use

```
DATEFROMPARTS(ConstructionYear, 1, 1)
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx

Comment: Well, in SQL 2012 this is also "the best answer" imho.

Answer (score 1):

This should WORK but there's probably a better way

```
CAST(CAST(ConstructionYear  as nvarchar(4)) + '-01-01' as datetime)
```

What your query is doing is taking the number of days you are providing and adding it to SQL servers epoch, January 1st, 1900, which gives the results you saw

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @y FLOAT;
SELECT @y = 2012;
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @y-1900, 0);
```

Why did you think the numeric value 2012 translated directly to a number of years? When in fact in SQL Server a numeric value translates to the number of days since 1900-01-01. So the following should yield the same results:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 2012);
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 2012, '19000101');
```

As others have suggested, I strongly suggest you to store this data correctly. While you could use something a little safer like `SMALLINT`, why not use `DATE`? This comes with built-in validation, ability to use all kinds of date/time functionality directly without conversion, and doesn't have any of the inherent rounding problems you might experience with an approximate data type like `FLOAT`. If you're storing a date, use a date data type.

Comment: I could clearly see that something was going on with the days, because incrementing the year by 1 would increase the day in the datetime by one.  I just didn't know that 1900 was the base year.

Also, i completely agree that FLOAT is not an appropriate way to store this data.  I wish i could change the structure of these tables, but unfortunately they are handed to me as is.

Comment: This is the best answer on this page. Use date math and date functions. Don't do silly string manipulation. People (not Aaron), stop thinking in terms of how it displays to you when it's formatted for human understanding. Start thinking how the computer works with the underlying data that represents the values!!!!